# Phrases gives different output from Phraser

Tags: gensim

I'm trying to generate bigrams and trigrams for an LDA topic modeling. My code is given below;

```
bigram = gensim.models.Phrases(data.normalized, min_count=5, threshold=5, 
                               connector_words=gensim.models.phrases.ENGLISH_CONNECTOR_WORDS)
bigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram)

trigram = gensim.models.Phrases(bigram_mod[data.normalized], min_count=5, threshold=2)
trigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(trigram)
```

For some reason, at least for one sample from the corpus, executing `trigram[sample]` gives me a different result than executing `trigram_mod[sample]`. My understanding is `trigram_mod` is the frozen phraser for `trigram`, and inherits the same parameters.

Why is the result different?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that shouldn't ever happen. Can you create a self-contained example that demonstrates the effect, either starting from training data (some data you can share or perhaps an already-public dataset), or starting from a `.save()`d instance of `Phrases` you can share (which would leak the word/bigram-frequency data of your dataset but not the full texts) that shows the problem with a test text?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. I'm not at liberty to share my dataset, but if its okay with you I could email you an invite to a private GitHub repository where I can share with you the pickled Phrases module. Are you good with that?

Comment: Ultimately we'd want something that could show the problem that could be shared in the Gensim Github repo, to whoever might be able to investigate. Also, there are a bunch of refactorings of the `Phrases` functionality in Gensim-4.0, including renaming the `Phraser` to `FrozenPhrases`. So it'd be useful to know if the problem can still be shown in the latest Gensim.

Comment: In that case I'll investigate further and see if I can reliably replicate the issue with data I can share. Meanwhile, I'll just avoid using the Phraser module, and directly use Phrases.

Comment: Another way to dig more would be to examine the state of the `Phrases` & `Phraser` around exactly whatever bigram is treated differently by `trigram` and `trigram_mod`. That is, boil your text down to a minimal, 2-token example. Examine the stats/thresholds in `trigram` & `trigram_mod` for just those 2 tokens, to figure out why they're passing the test to be combined in one & not other. (This will likely point directly to what step, in either the creation of the `trigram_mod` or after, where the problem arises.) Of course such analysis more valuable if in current Gensim-4.0's `FrozenPhraser`.